# Truncating last visible line of NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to create a NSTextField with 2 lines which is truncated at the end of the second line with 3 dots: "..." . In Interface Builder it is possible to check the "Truncates Last Visible Line" box. How can I do this programmatically in Swift? I tried the following:

```
label.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

But this doesn't add the 3 dots at the end. When I switch out the second line with: `label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` the first line is truncated at the end and there is no second line at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set that on the `cell` property of `NSTextField` as follows:

```
label.cell?.truncatesLastVisibleLine = true
```

Comment: @user2403221, Glad to help